# Add a character to a specific part of a string?

Tags: r, string

I have a list of file names as such:

```
"A/B/file.jpeg"

"A/C/file2.jpeg"

"B/C/file3.jpeg"
```

and a couple of variations of such.

My question is how would I be able to add a "new" or any characters into each of these file names after the second "/" such that the length of the string/name doesn't matter just that it is placed after the second "/"

Results would ideally be:

```
"A/B/newfile.jpeg"

"A/B/newfile2.jpeg" etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub`.

```
gsub('(file)', 'new\\1', x)
# [1] "A/B/newfile.jpeg"  "A/C/newfile2.jpeg" "B/C/newfile3.jpeg"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("A/B/file.jpeg", "A/C/file2.jpeg", "B/C/file3.jpeg")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I did not see it prior to my edits as I am on mobile. But would this just assume the A/B/ is constant and not using the / / positions?

Comment: @JimboBiggly Yes sorry, see update.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_replace`:

```r
library(stringr)

l <- c("A/B/file.jpeg", "A/B/file2.jpeg", "A/B/file3.jpeg")

str_replace(l, "\\/(?=file)", "\\/new")

#> [1] "A/B/newfile.jpeg"  "A/B/newfile2.jpeg" "A/B/newfile3.jpeg"
```

Comment: Does this assume that A/B/ is constant or does it just look at the second / placement and place the "new" after it ? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes, my solution looks for the second `/` and replaces that with `/new`, @JimboBiggly.